# Перезаписать содержомое блока

Tags: html, jquery

Есть блок html. Я добавил на страницу кнопку, при клике на которую происходит `alert( $("some_div").html() )`.

Все работает как надо. Вопрос в том, когда меняю содержимое блока `html`, то при клике на кнопку отображается не измененный блок, а его первоначальное состояние. Например, в блоке у меня есть текстовый input, я меняю в нем значение, и при `alert( $("some_div").html() )` он показывает мне старое значение. Так вот вопрос в том, как мне получить все содержимое, но обновленное?

```
<button class="show_me">Alert</button>
<div class="content">
    <input type="text" value="22" />
</div>


$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".show_me").click(function(e)
    {
        alert( $(".content").html() );
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Добавьте отрывок из кода...

Comment: Добавил код html и javascript

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы вписываете что-то в input, то html код на самом деле не меняется.
Поэтому метод .html() будет давать инпуты с изначальными значениями value.

Как вариант вы можете либо привязать на keyup обновление атрибута value

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
  $(this).attr('value', $(this).val());
});
```

Либо при клике на кнопку обновить все инпуты, например так

```
$('input').each(function(){
  $(this).attr('value', $(this).val());
});
```

Возможно, есть более элегантные и правильные методы.

Comment: Да, я так и сделал, только повесил на событие onChange

Comment: А как быть с селектами?